# Voice to text: How punctuation works in Dutch?

Tags: voice-recognition

I've seen a lot of post about the punctuation, but that was all about the English version of voice-to-text.

The Dutch version works pretty good, but it seems to be imposible to do things like 'new line', 'point' or 'comma'.

How to use the punctuation in Dutch?

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no support yet for punctuation marks in Dutch. Unless something has changed since this posting:

[Spraakgestuurd typen met deze 10 tips en trucs](https://computertotaal.nl/artikelen/apps-software/spraakgestuurd-typen-met-deze-10-tips-en-trucs-70289/)

(Scroll down to "Tip 04: Leestekens")

I came across this while searching for Japanese punctuation in voice input. Try using Swype Keyboard app as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

So far these work for me (Dutch):

- punt . of punt punt punt ...
- komma ,
- dubbele punt :
- punt komma ;
- uitroepteken !
- vraagteken ?
- slash /
- back slash \
- hekje #
- apestaartje @
- ampersand &
- sterretje *
- accolade { (of } daarna)
- procent (alleen direct achter een getal) 1%
- Euro (zoals: drie euro veertien) €3,14
- nieuwe regel
- nieuwe alinea

Comment: Welcome on the Android SE! I think your answer would look better with using some phonetic alphabet, too :-) No prob if you can't, possible a future editor will insert it.